# Accessing Excel files directly from RAM using Excel Writer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

In the documentation for [pd.ExcelWriter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) we see the following code snippet:

You can store Excel file in RAM:

```
import io
df = pd.DataFrame([["ABC", "XYZ"]], columns=["Foo", "Bar"])
buffer = io.BytesIO()
with pd.ExcelWriter(buffer) as writer:
     df.to_excel(writer)
```

My question is that how can we access the excel back. I wanted to have the b64 coded version of the same excel without saving the file in the system that is why I am thinking of saving it in my RAM. Can someone please help on this?

Thanks for your time

*Solution*: Was able to access the file using buffer.getvalue().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the snippet you provided, the Excel file has been written to the `buffer` the same way as if it would have been stored on disk.

Therefore you can read it back in a similar way as if you were reading from file:

```
pd.read_excel(buffer.getvalue())
```

More on how `BytesIO` behave:

- [Create an excel file from BytesIO using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59348309/create-an-excel-file-from-bytesio-using-python)
- [Difference between `open` and `io.BytesIO` in binary streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42800250/difference-between-open-and-io-bytesio-in-binary-streams)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this but it is not working.  Getting a Value Error. ValueError: File is not a recognized excel file. Any other way in which we can access it ?

Comment: Hi, was able to access the data using buffer.getvalue() method. Thanks for your help sophros